# Hello World example using the JRedis client

Tags: redis

I want to use Redis with Java so I started with [this](https://github.com/alphazero/jredis/blob/1.2.n/examples/src/main/java/org/jredis/examples/HelloAgain.java) simple example (see the code below).

The first run inserts a key,value pair to the database and the second run should get the value and print it to screen. There are two problems that I don't understand:

1. When I insert the key it prints out an error that the value is not a command: "Error response for PING => ERR unknown command "Hello Again!". This does not make sense to me -- why does it think that the String value is a command?
2. When I run it a second time to print the value for the key, it only prints the length of the value but I expected to see "Hello Again!" printed.

Thanks for the help!

Here's the code:

```
import org.jredis.ClientRuntimeException;
import org.jredis.JRedis;
import org.jredis.ProviderException;
import org.jredis.RedisException;
import org.jredis.protocol.Command;
import org.jredis.ri.alphazero.JRedisClient;
import static org.jredis.ri.alphazero.support.DefaultCodec.*;

/**
 * [TODO: document me!]
 *
 * @author  Joubin Houshyar (alphazero@sensesay.net)
 * @version alpha.0, Apr 15, 2009
 * @since   alpha.0
 * 
 */

public class HelloAgain {
    public static final String key = "jredis::examples::HelloAgain::message";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String password = "";
        if(args.length > 0) password  = args[0];
        new HelloAgain().run(password);
    }

    private void run(String password) {
        try {
            JRedis  jredis = new JRedisClient("localhost", 6379, "jredis", 0);
            jredis.ping();

            if(!jredis.exists(key)) {
                jredis.set(key, "Hello Again!");
                System.out.format("Hello!  You should run me again!\n");
            }
            else {
                String msg = toStr ( jredis.get(key) );
                System.out.format("%s\n", msg);
            }
            jredis.quit();
        }
        catch (RedisException e){
            if (e.getCommand()==Command.PING){
                System.out.format("I'll need that password!  Try again with password as command line arg for this program.\n");
            }
        }
        catch (ProviderException e){
            System.out.format("Oh no, an 'un-documented feature':  %s\nKindly report it.", e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (ClientRuntimeException e){
            System.out.format("%s\n", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I didn't get any answer and also tried the author of this example but with no luck. I did some reading and found out that [jedis](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis) is a better Java client for Redis. I tried it out and it works perfectly; very simple to use.

Answer (score 1):

The author was busy with his day job which was in fact spanning the evening hours as well.  I am sure you understand.

I have looked at Jedis and it is a very good client and has quite excellent performance and as of this post provides a greater feature set (cf above); but I do not see any reduction of complexity in usage.  The API of JRedis is the Redis command set -- no more, no less.  JRedis may appear "complex" to some, but the experienced users will recognize its modular design is there to allow for you to utilize it beyond merely a client, should you choose to, for example, write your own specialized client using the JRedis RI components such as the Protocol, Connector, etc.

The problem you were having is due to a mismatch between the Redis server version -- which had a change in its wire protocol -- and the JRedis version.  Current master branch of JRedis has been updated to conform to Redis 2.2.n.  As always, read the compliance note at the project root to make sure you are using the correctly matched Redis server.